# Access to a Server that contain postfix and use it to send mail from spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, ssh

I'm creating a service in a spring boot application to send email using postfix server , the problem is that postfix is not installed in my machine, to get into postfix i should connect to remote server via ssh and then use the postfix ( **the postfix is inside a Docker container in the remote server**) so inside the remote machine a should use **telnet** to connect to postfix .

Now the problem is how can i connect spring boot to postfix ? in the application.properties a have these following properties:

```
spring.mail.host=

spring.mail.port=

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=false
```

what should fill inside the host and the port properties ?

Please, If there's any suggestion, do not hesitate.

Thank You !

Comment: you can take remote server IP address and port used for postfix and give the same here , Note :from spring boot deployed server you should have access to the remote server or you can try docker inspect <postifxcontainer> in this you can see the IP address try with that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just taking a step back to highlight the top level constructs and how they "usually" fit together.

1 At a certain level of abstraction we can view a  "postfix server" as a server with a mail queue where your sent  emails are stored pending being sent down the Port 25 SMTP (email) pipe.

2 We can send emails easily via this pipe in java using the [java mail api](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) [1].

Note this is available in Java SE so we can use it from spring boot. While Spring probably has various email packages we could exploit,  using java Mail API can be good for code reuse outside of any Spring ecosystem

3 When using [1] at a high level we first construct a session object

```
val session = Session.getInstance(<some properties>, <some auth scheme can be null)
```

we would then constuct a email message object with this session

```
    val msg = new MimeMessage(session)
```

we would then send it on to the postfix mailq with the Transport static class

```
    Transport.send(msg);
```

As long as this happens on the "postfix server" and the session and message objects are constructed correctly then your message should end up in the mailq and get sent down the pipe.
Lots of the details can be found in the java doc for the mail api starting [here](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html)

Summary
Spring boot app with java mail api running on a server with postfix set up.